# Why do results from optim() depend on initial values?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

In R, I am using the function optim() to find the minimum of an objective function of two variables.  The real objective functions I'm working with are quite complex, so I tried to familiarize myself with the a simpler objective function. The simplest way to run optim() is optim(par,function) where par is a vector of initial values for the algorithm.  I find that the answer I get depends heavily on the initial values I input.  However, the function I used is so simple, I'm worried that I am misunderstanding either the input or output of optim().

The objective function I am using is:

```
f <- function(x){
    abs(x[1])*abs(x[2])
}
```

When I run `optim(c(-1.2,1),f)` and `optim(c(-1.2,10),f)` I get drastically different output for the optimal arguments (par) and the minimum (value).  Does anyone have an idea why this would be so?

Comment: Ths short answer is because  `optim` try to find a **local** maxima and minima of functions, by varying parameters in some direction.

Comment: That's not very encouraging.  The objective function I'm using is not terribly behaved.  Is there a different function that I could worry about less?

Comment: You could try to do stochastic global optimization via e.g. `method="SANN"` in `optim()`, or searching the [Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) for "global" will give you more options.  However, be warned: global optimization is in general **not easy**, and you will usually have to spend some time tuning an algorithm to your particular case.

Comment: But your function also has infinitely many optimal points in this case. Anywhere one of the two parameters is 0, the value is 0. So who is to say the zero at `(0, 0)` is any better than the zero at `(0, 3.4)`.

Comment: @MrFlick, better point.  My comment is a good answer to some questions, but not to this one.  (You should draw a picture of the objective function surface and post it as an answer ...)

Comment: Yes, you are all correct.  That was just a stupid example function I had picked.

Comment: I wish this question could be deleted, because it just adds to the clutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case your objective function has infinitely many optimal points (not necessarily just different local maxima). Anywhere one of the parameters is zero 0 is just as good as any other point where a parameter is near 0. I'm not sure if you were expecting (0,0), but (0,34) has the same value and can also be considered optimal.

[image: objective function]

Comment: Nice. I considered adding a 3d plot to show this but the heatmap approach is probably much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

An associated function is:

```
g <- function(x, y) abs(x)*abs(y)
```

We can visualize the levels of the graph with `contour` and plot the points given:

A reasonable field given your initial and final conditions (noted from running `optim`):

```
x <- seq(-1.5, 0, by=.1)
y <- seq(0, 11, by=1)
```

A matrix of the values in `g`:

```
m <- outer(x, y, g)
```

Plot the results, including the results of `optim`.  Note that the values at `x==0` or `y==0` are optimal.

```
contour(x, y, m)
o1 <- optim(c(-1.2,1),f)$par
o2 <- optim(c(-1.2,10),f)$par
segments(-1.2, 1, o1[1], o1[2], col='red')
segments(-1.2, 10, o2[1], o2[2], col='red')
# Add zero lines as contour does not draw them
segments(0, 11, 0, 0)
segments(-1.5, 0, 0, 0)
```

This shows a straight line from the initial condition (left side) to the zero of the function (right side).  Note that the optimization does not follow a straight line, but this shows that it is reasonable that quite different results will be achieved.

[image]