# Why "optimx" in R give different results when changing the starting values?

Tags: r, optimization

I need to to use "optimx" but I found that the output changes when I change the starting values.Is this normal or there is error in my script?:

```
  dat1 <- array(1:60, c(3,5,4));dat2 <- array(1:60, c(3,5,4));dat3 <- array(1:60, c(3,5,4))
  #reorder dimensions 
  dat1 <- aperm(dat1, c(3,1,2)); dat2 <- aperm(dat2, c(3,1,2));dat3 <- aperm(dat3, c(3,1,2))
   #make array a matrix 
  dat1a <- dat1;dim(dat1a) <- c(dim(dat1)[1],prod(dim(dat1)[2:3])) 
  dat2a <- dat2;dim(dat2a) <- c(dim(dat2)[1],prod(dim(dat2)[2:3])) 
  dat3a <- dat3;dim(dat3a) <- c(dim(dat3)[1],prod(dim(dat3)[2:3]))
```

case one:

```
   fun <- function(x1, x2, y) {
    keep <- !(is.na(x1) | is.na(x2) | is.na(y))
     if (sum(keep) > 0) { 
        best=function(p,x1, x2, y){
   sum((y [keep]-(((p[1]*x1[keep]+p[2]*x2[keep]+p[3])^p[4])+p[5]))^2)}
      res <- optimx(c(0.5,3,4,0.1,1.8),best,x1=x1,x2=x2,y=y)
     res  <- coef(res)[1:5] 
      } else {    res <- c(NA, NA, NA,NA,NA)  }
         return(res)}

     res2 <- mapply(fun, x1=as.data.frame(dat1a), x2=as.data.frame(dat2a), y=as.data.frame(dat3a))
```

res2:

```
        V1         V2         V3          V4         V5         V6         V7
[1,] -6.4508094  4.3192551 -4.4118228  0.96978160 -5.3236129  1.7360552  6.7636543
[2,] -0.7073374 -0.7404623 -0.7490429 -0.56937504 -0.6729419 -0.7373379 -0.7387721
```

case two:

```
   # same function but I changed the starting values
    fun=function(x1, x2, y) {
       keep <- !(is.na(x1) | is.na(x2) | is.na(y))
       if (sum(keep) > 0) { 
    best=function(p,x1, x2, y){
        sum((y [keep]-(((p[1]*x1[keep]+p[2]*x2[keep]+p[3])^p[4])+p[5]))^2)}
    res <- optimx(c(1,1,1,1,1),best,x1=x1,x2=x2,y=y)
    res  <- coef(res)[1:5] 
} else {   res <- c(NA, NA, NA,NA,NA)    }
return(res)}
 res3 <- mapply(fun, x1=as.data.frame(dat1a), x2=as.data.frame(dat2a), y=as.data.frame(dat3a))
```

res3:

```
 V1         V2         V3         V4        V5        V6         V7        V8
 [1,]  0.6018246  0.1993663 -0.2520812 -0.1702029 -1.176793 -6.513526 -0.1749120 -1.329519
 [2,]  7.6637890  3.4957285  3.0466838  2.2510481  1.601970  1.245830  1.0175985  0.852469
```

Comment: Aside from the question note that `dat1a` and `dat2a` are the same so `x1` and `x2` are the same and the model  is not indentifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error in your script. This is the way the optimiser works. In your case you are using `optimx` with the default parameters (i.e. method is not specified as well as upper and lower arguments) which means that internally `optimx` will use the base R `optim` function with the default `Nelder-Mead` method.

I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) (which might not be the best source but it explains it correctly):

> The Nelder–Mead method or downhill simplex method or amoeba method is a commonly used nonlinear optimization technique, which is a well-defined numerical method for problems for which derivatives may not be known. However, the Nelder–Mead technique is a **heuristic** search method that can converge to non-stationary points[1] on problems that can be solved by alternative methods.[2]

The keyword in the above quote, which I have highlighted is **heuristic**:

> Heuristic, is any approach to problem solving, learning, or discovery that employs a practical methodology not guaranteed to be optimal or perfect, but sufficient for the immediate goals.

Therefore, the `optim` function is trying to find a local minima in your case that will provide a fast sub-optimal solution (i.e. it doesn't find the global minima). This happens for speed and computational purposes.

So, by changing the initial values you change the starting point of the method and therefore each time you get a different local minima.

The rest of the methods work in a similar way but it makes sense to research each method to figure out whether a heuristic solutions is being calculated or not.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796407/why-do-results-from-optim-depend-on-initial-values) is another similar question I found which gives a good explanation.

Comment: Aside from the fact that `dat1a`, `dat2a`, `dat3a` are exactly the same as mentioned in the comments and that the function throws an error because of that, I think that your functions are ok based on the output you provided. It is expected to get different results for different starting values.

Comment: I don't think there is one to be honest just because some times the solutions are too many to compute in a finite time. Therefore, most algorithms use heuristic ways. Check the documentation of `optim` by typing `?optim`. The best way to figure out whether a function would try to find the optimal solution would be to read papers about how these methods are implemented.

Comment: I had a look at the other question and the answer is the same as this. In that case there is (most likely) one (in which case global) or few local minima so `optim` always returns the same values. The reason it might not return the same values but approximations is that these algorithms in many cases return approximate solutions instead of precise (again for computational reasons). I suggest you read that wiki link and the heuristic link inside there. You will find a lot of answers. Don't dive into the maths if you don't want to.